# Hyperthreading not detected by Linux

Tags: linux, centos, cpu, hyperthreading

I have a Dell server with two Intel Xeon E5645 cpus, each cpu has 6 cores, and each core is hyperthreaded (i.e. should be equivalent to two virtual cores). I installed CentOS 6.2 on this server and it seems to detect only 12 cores (although there should be 24 virtual cores altogether).

When I look at `/proc/cpuinfo` I get for each cpu:

```
cpu cores: 6
siblings: 6
```

Which seems to indicate that number of cores equals number of virtual cores, or hyperthreading not detected/enabled.

When I run `dmidecode` I can see that HT flag is turned on and I do see the following, which seem to indicate that the BIOS is configured correctly for hyperthreading.

```
Core Count: 6
Core Enabled: 6
Thread Count: 12
```

Is there some configuration that I am missing in order to make Linux detect all virtual cores?

Comment: The processor model is Intel Xeon E5645

Comment: What says if you type `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: I get the following: 12

Comment: There isn't anything special that has to be done on our dual E5649 box. Except make sure its on in the BIOS. (Ours is Supermicro, not Dell. And Debian, not CentOS)

Comment: What kernel are you using?

Comment: The kernel version is 2.6.32

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer; isn't needed to edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your BIOS settings, i.e. if hyperthreading is not turned on in your BIOS, then it is not operational.

Comment: The OP says: "When I run dmidecode I can see that HT flag is turned on and I do see the following, which seem to indicate that the BIOS is configured correctly for hyperthreading."

Comment: I checked. The BIOS settings seem okay. To the best of my understanding the relevant option is "logical processor" and it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux kernel configuration, there's an option called

> CONFIG_NR_CPUS

Its description in the kernel documentation:

> This allows you to specify the maximum number of CPUs which this
>   kernel will support.  The maximum supported value is 512 and the
>   minimum value which makes sense is 2.

Check this value, and increase it if needed. Of course, you need to re-compile your kernel afterwards.

Comment: Here are the relevant config options on my server. They all seem ok to me.CONFIG_MAXSMP=y
CONFIG_NR_CPUS=4096
CONFIG_SCHED_SMT=y